# Examining a iTunesConnect rejection crash log

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, exc-bad-access

I am attempting to get my first SpriteKit game into the app store. It was rejected on the basis of a crash, but I can't replicate it. I have tried running the same archive on devices and have looked over the crash report. Maybe I am missing something. `[PKPhysicsBody dealloc]` is also confusing as that does not exist. The following is the report:

Your app crashed on launch. This occurred when your app was used:

- On Wi-Fi
- On cellular network

  ```
  Incident Identifier: 2AF5DCC3-3B9D-47E9-81C7-9D68CD7D8560
  CrashReporter Key:   1b565a0649bcb9a768618a9e56a78c389c26cc14
  Hardware Model:      xxx
  Process:             QuartzRun [238]
  Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/2E6AF70A-3918-4409-92C4-A63DDFED3835/QuartzRun.app/QuartzRun
  Identifier:          com.keelyhill.QuartzRun
  Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
  Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
  Parent Process:      launchd [1]

  Date/Time:           2014-03-05 09:38:05.915 -0800
  OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
  Report Version:      104

  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
  Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbaddf80c8da7beb5
  Triggered by Thread:  0

  Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
  Thread 0 Crashed:
  0   PhysicsKit                      0x000000018e47a1ac -[PKPhysicsBody dealloc] + 40
  1   PhysicsKit                      0x000000018e47a3e8 -[PKPhysicsBody initWithRectangleOfSize:] + 272

  2   PhysicsKit                      0x000000018e47afa0 +[PKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:] + 64
  3   SpriteKit                       0x000000018982e528 +[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:] + 32
  4   QuartzRun                       -[Game loadLevel] (Game.m:156)
  5   QuartzRun                       0x000000010001d7b0 0x100018000 + 22448
  6   SpriteKit                       0x00000001897f30d8 +[SKScene sceneWithSize:] + 84
  7   QuartzRun                       0x0000000100024628 0x100018000 + 50728
  8   SpriteKit                       0x00000001897f30d8 +[SKScene sceneWithSize:] + 84
  9   QuartzRun                       0x0000000100022f84 0x100018000 + 44932
  10  QuartzRun                       0x0000000100022ffc 0x100018000 + 45052
  11  UIKit                           0x0000000189936d24 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 264
  12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001895330c8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
  13  QuartzCore                      0x000000018952dc90 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 296
  14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189560bc4 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 200
  15  UIKit                           0x00000001899bd5c0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 4124
  16  UIKit                           0x00000001899bc51c -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 124
  17  UIKit                           0x000000018993e074 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
  18  UIKit                           0x00000001899bbb48 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 188
  19  UIKit                           0x000000018994399c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 520
  20  UIKit                           0x0000000189940aac -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 304
  21  UIKit                           0x00000001899b4888 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 64
  22  UIKit                           0x00000001899b11ec -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2048
  23  UIKit                           0x00000001899aa99c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 768
  24  UIKit                           0x000000018993d52c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3332
  25  UIKit                           0x000000018993c71c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 100
  26  UIKit                           0x00000001899aa0ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 708
  27  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c349124 _PurpleEventCallback + 672
  28  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c348c50 PurpleEventCallback + 44
  29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186a26fc4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
  30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186a26f24 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
  31  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186a25148 __CFRunLoopRun + 1616
  32  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186965b34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
  33  UIKit                           0x00000001899a92d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 780
  34  UIKit                           0x00000001899a40e4 UIApplicationMain + 1152
  35  QuartzRun                       0x0000000100024ec0 0x100018000 + 52928
  36  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001934a7a9c start + 0

  Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
  Thread 1:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193589ac8 kevent64 + 8
  1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019348dd74 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

  Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.gamecenter.GKDaemonProxy
  Thread 2:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193589cfc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
  1   GameCenterFoundation            0x00000001877d3a2c __35-[GKDaemonProxy buildServiceLookup]_block_invoke + 576
  2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019348c41c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
  3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019348c3dc _dispatch_client_callout + 12
  4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934926ec _dispatch_queue_drain + 540
  5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019348e880 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 64
  6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001934933a4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 312
  7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000193493634 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
  8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000193621914 _pthread_wqthread + 352
  9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936217a4 start_wqthread + 0

  Thread 3:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935a2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936217a4 start_wqthread + 0

  Thread 4:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935a2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936217a4 start_wqthread + 0

  Thread 5:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935a2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936217a4 start_wqthread + 0

  Thread 6:
  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001935a2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001936217a4 start_wqthread + 0

  Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
      x0: 0x00000001701a80a0   x1: 0x0000000189fbd5b0   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x00000001935dbd18
      x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000002
      x8: 0xbaddf80c8da7bead   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000360600  x11: 0x0000000000000000
     x12: 0x00000000001f9300  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000300  x15: 0x0000000000800000
     x16: 0x000000019361d144  x17: 0x000000018e47a184  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000134520970
     x20: 0x00000001701a80a0  x21: 0x0000000134520970  x22: 0x0000000189fbd5cf  x23: 0x0000000193eb5b48
     x24: 0x0000000100030000  x25: 0x0000000189855882  x26: 0x0000000189fcb0fa  x27: 0x00000001700eaf80
     x28: 0x0000000134510b40  fp: 0x000000016fde3930   lr: 0x000000018e47a3ec
      sp: 0x000000016fde3910   pc: 0x000000018e47a1ac cpsr: 0x60000000
  ```

  Binary Images:
  I left out of the post

Here is [Game loadlevel] (the concerned part):

```
            SKSpriteNode *top = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"top"];
        top.size = CGSizeMake(top.size.width, top.size.height/1.5);
        top.position = CGPointMake(i * top.size.width, self.size.height - top.size.height/3.5);
        /* This is line 156 */ top.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(top.size.width, top.size.height - 32 * iPad)];

        top.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0f;
        top.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        top.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        top.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = backgroundCategory;
```

The iPad param is a int I have in the prefix.pch. It is set to 1 or 2 in the app delegate depending on the device. I found out if this is 0, it will crash.

The code int the app delegate did Finnish launching:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) iPad = 2;
else iPad = 1;
```

Comment: If you don't have a `dealloc` method (it would have been generated by ARC if you don't have an explicit one) then post the code for your `[PKPhysicsBody initWithRectangleOfSize:]` method.

Comment: @rmaddy, what is confusing is there is no `[PKPhysicsBody initWithRectangleOfSize:]` method or any PKPhysicsBody. SpriteKit has a SKPhysics though. (ARC is on)

Comment: There is obviously such a method or it wouldn't appear in the stack trace. Did you create the `PKPhysicsBody` class?

Comment: @rmaddy. No, I don't have a class of PKPhysicsBody, that is part of my confusion. I think it is part of apples private sprite kit framework, but there is a PK instead of SK for some reason.

Comment: Apple has a private PhysicsKit framework, which does declare a PKPhysicsBody class, which has a `initWithRectangeOfSize:` initializer, so that shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report so your own apps calls in that stack trace will reveal your code.

Comment: Finally got symboling right. The closest my code is in [Game loadlevel]. I updated the post with that code.

Comment: Sounds as if the object gets an invalid size. Or even worse, maybe "top" actually is `nil`. Did make sure your level-data is distributed correctly into the app-store?

Comment: @Till. Checked, top is not nil if iPad is 0. Also, all level data is in app. All I can see is that physics body does not like {0,0} size.

Comment: Well then the solution is simple, isn't it? Just don't try to allocate such objects when they don't have a valid size, no?

Comment: Good point, but I am confused as to why 'iPad' should ever be 0. I am still not sure if it is when apple reviewers run it.